# Is it possible to condition a MSBUILD target to only run when the Run/Debug/F5 command is pressed>

Tags: msbuild, targets

I would like to set a condition on a MSBUILD Target that would have it run only when the Start Debugging menu item or F5 key is pressed.  If the user just uses the Build menu item.. I don't want the Target to run.

Comment: Is that something to run before the real program to debug into, or a different option to build the EXE when you'll be using the debugger?

Comment: Debugging is completely independent from building: msbuild isn't invoked when you start debugging. Or, if you have set the project to build when it's out of date and starting debugging, it will first build then debug but those two steps are still independent and the first one is the same as starting a normal build. What you want is probably only doable by creating an extension which first builds with the condition and then starts debugging. Maybe you should explain what you want to do exactly and another solution might pop up

Answer (score 0):

Conditions on targets are evaluated when the project is loaded. If the condition is false it won't be executed even if the condition value changes.

What you may be able to do is hook in a target to execute and then condition the tasks. Or use CallTarget with a condition.